# How to get just one output when a SELECT is in a loop?

Tags: sql, sql-server

This is my code, at the end you can find the output. Basically there are 2 outputs. 
So, how can I get just one output on this situation:

#### SQL

```
DECLARE 
@SubcategoriaId [nvarchar] (15),
@Nombre [nvarchar](50),
@Descripcion [nvarchar](100),
@CantProd [numeric] (4,0)

-- Declaring the cursor
DECLARE XX_Cursor CURSOR
FOR SELECT subcategoria.SubcategoriaId, subcategoria.Nombre, subcategoria.Descripcion
FROM subcategoria 
WHERE subcategoria.Categoria = 'Ca_2E006CC3'


OPEN XX_Cursor

-- I save the first cursor result into the variables @SubcategoriaId, @Nombre, @Descripcion
FETCH NEXT FROM XX_Cursor INTO @SubcategoriaId, @Nombre, @Descripcion


WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
BEGIN

    SET @CantProd = (SELECT count(*) FROM TEST_COLUMN)

   -- with this select I will get a lot of rows but on a different requests because this is in a loop 
   Select @SubcategoriaId AS ID, @Nombre AS Name, @Descripcion AS Description, @CantProd AS Cant

   FETCH NEXT FROM XX_Cursor INTO @SubcategoriaId, @Nombre, @Descripcion
END

CLOSE XX_Cursor
DEALLOCATE XX_Cursor
```

#### Output

This is the output:

```
ID          | Name                            | Description                     | Cant   
Sc_7EAFEDED | Desc Subcategoria desde WEB 2.2 | Desc Subcategoria desde WEB 2.2 |  3

ID          | Name                            | Description                     | Cant   
Sc_7EAFEKMD | Desc Subcategoria desde WEB 1.1 | Desc Subcategoria desde WEB 1.1 |  1
```

But I need something like this:

```
ID          | Name                            | Description                     | Cant   
Sc_7EAFEDED | Desc Subcategoria desde WEB 2.2 | Desc Subcategoria desde WEB 2.2 |  3 
Sc_7EAFEKMD | Desc Subcategoria desde WEB 1.1 | Desc Subcategoria desde WEB 1.1 |  1
```

Comment: It's not clear at all, from what you've shown, why you're using a cursor at all. Is your real query larger than what you've shown?

Comment: there are multiple other ways to add a count of records as a column. Is this your real query?

Comment: Please note that tags stand alone.  That is, you can't combine multiple tags to create a single concept.  The tags `[sql]` and `[server]` together aren't the same thing as the single `[sql-server]` tag.  **Always be sure to read the descriptions that appear when selecting tags!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You create a variable table and put the data on it, then you select the content from the temptable

You could also replace @MyTempTable by a temp table using #MyTempTable  instead

```
DECLARE 
@SubcategoriaId [nvarchar] (15),
@Nombre [nvarchar](50),
@Descripcion [nvarchar](100),
@CantProd [numeric] (4,0)

DECLARE @MyTempTable TABLE (ID varchar(255), Name  varchar(255), Description varchar(255), Cant INT)

-- Declaring the cursor
DECLARE XX_Cursor CURSOR
FOR SELECT subcategoria.SubcategoriaId, subcategoria.Nombre, subcategoria.Descripcion
FROM subcategoria 
WHERE subcategoria.Categoria = 'Ca_2E006CC3'


OPEN XX_Cursor

-- I save the first cursor result into the variables @SubcategoriaId, @Nombre, @Descripcion
FETCH NEXT FROM XX_Cursor INTO @SubcategoriaId, @Nombre, @Descripcion


WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
BEGIN

    SET @CantProd = (SELECT count(*) FROM TEST_COLUMN)

   -- with this select I will get a lot of rows but on a different requests because this is in a loop 
INSERT INTO @MyTempTable (ID, Name, Description, Cant)
   Select @SubcategoriaId AS ID, @Nombre AS Name, @Descripcion AS Description, @CantProd AS Cant

   FETCH NEXT FROM XX_Cursor INTO @SubcategoriaId, @Nombre, @Descripcion
END

CLOSE XX_Cursor
DEALLOCATE XX_Cursor

SELECT * FROM @MyTempTable
```

Answer (score 0):

How about getting rid of the cursor. There is a lot of debate on using or not cursors, but for querying data cursors should not be used. The following code would work for MSSQL 2005 and newer but querys can be done for older also :

```
 SELECT 
     subcategoria.SubcategoriaId
     , subcategoria.Nombre
     , subcategoria.Descripcion
 FROM subcategoria sc
 cross apply (
   SELECT count(*) FROM TEST_COLUMN WHERE ...... (I do not know what table is this but I guess you missed some where clauses)
 )
 WHERE subcategoria.Categoria = 'Ca_2E006CC3'
```